# LXC SSH too slow in CentOS7

Tags: centos, ssh, centos7, lxc

I have a newly created centos7. I installed the LXC and create a configuration:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.hwaddr = fe:84:8b:f1:76:8e
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/lon-staging-nginx1.web.com/rootfs
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/centos.common.conf
lxc.arch = x86_64
lxc.utsname = lon-staging-nginx1.web.com
lxc.network.ipv4  =  192.168.42.110/24
lxc.network.ipv4.gateway  =  192.168.42.1
lxc.mount.entry = /root/staging-test vagrant/ none bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /srv/www/cdn srv/www/cdn/ none bind 0 0
lxc.mount.entry = /srv/www/main-application/app srv/www/web/ none bind 0 0
```

I start it and I can ping it from the host without problem. From the host to other VMs I can SSH without problem. The VMs on SoftLayer and the SSH between VMs are working. When I want to SSH to the container I try this:

```
ssh -vvvv root@192.168.42.110
```

I tried the *UseDNS no* and *GSSAPIAuthentication no* but these didn't help for me. 
The connection staneding in this position:

```
...    
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.42.110" from file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
    debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
    debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
    debug1: Host '192.168.42.110' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
    debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
    debug2: kex_derive_keys
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fce34aff920),
    debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
    debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
    debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
```

After a long time start with it:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
```

I looked with *time ssh ...* command and the triing time was

```
real    5m27.966s
user    0m0.021s
sys 0m0.001s
```

Comment: `strace` things  to find out gaps between timestamps.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VwN0frJQ

Comment: In this log, there is only 1 minute. Also you limited `strace` to `open` only, which is usually not the issue.

Comment: I save it to a log fileand yhow you, but if I connect to the container with lxc-attach and ssh to the host it is working without problem. From the host I can ssh everywhere without problem just only to this container had problems.

Comment: @Jakuje There is the result http://pastebin.com/exSMKg6v

Comment: Still I see only 60s wait for data from server side. Give a try to the same procedure on the server (watching server with `strace`, but note that you need switches to trace children). It also depends how your sshd service starts in container, but attaching to running daemon seems like the best case.

Comment: Reload the all os and now it is working, I haven't idea what was the problem. Thanks for the help.